# Codeigniter Non-static method MY_Loader::define_module() should not be called statically

Tags: php, codeigniter, vagrant, centos6, ioncube

I'm attemptng to run a codeigniter site locally on a vargrant CentOS VM.  I have downloaded all the files, and set up the yaml / host file etc.

I am getting this error on screen

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: Non-static method MY_Loader::define_module() should not be
>   called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
>
> Filename: controllers/Front_Controller.php
>
> Line Number: 43

This file looks compiled, but does reference ionCube.  I had to install that as well, but that has all been done. I can't see why I'm getting this error.

Could the PHP / ioncube version be an issue?  On the live site, it is running PHP 5.2.17 and 4.0.7 (i'm on 5.6 and 4.7.5 locally).

Can't see whats going on.

Comment: Do you get the error on the local machine, or on your server?

Comment: On the local machine

Comment: And the server runs fine, or did you not try it as of yet?

Comment: There server is fine.  I've taken a copy of all the files and db from live to make amends locally before pushing changes up.

Comment: Just to make sure: You have purchased an ionCube encoded script that triggers the error, right? You are not encoding the script yourself? Can you provide some code for context, and which plugin might be causing this error?

Comment: I haven't purchased anything.  ive simply taken a copy of all files from the live site and tried to run it locally.  I had to install ioncube in my vm as well. I dont think it is a plugin causing the error, it just seems to be crashing on the Front_Controller, which in turn references ioncube.  I'm not sure if that is the problem, and as mentioned, the file looks compiled, or minimised.

Comment: Seems like your Front_Controller.php is outdated: In PHP 5.2 functions could be called statically without `$this`, which is now deprecated, therefore the warning in PHP 5.6. Try running it on PHP 5.2 locally, or create a ticket at http://support.ioncube.com for further support

Answer (score 0):

You can change line 43 of Front_Controller.php to instantiate the class like:

```
$loaderObj = new MY_Loader();
$loaderObj->define_module($module . '/');
```

instead of

```
MY_Loader::define_module($module . '/');
```